# passing ref to a function from html

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have collapsible sections on the page that I would like to collapse on mouse click. The state is represented by the following 2 refs:

```
import type { Ref } from 'vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const isSection1Collapsed = ref(false)
const isSection2Collapsed = ref(false)
```

The generic method to toggle the display style:

```
const toggleCollapse = (target: Ref<boolean>) => {
  target.value = !target.value
}
```

For the HTML:

```
<div
  @click="toggleCollapse(isSection1Collapsed)"
  :class={'isCollapsed': isSection1Collapsed}>
  Section 1
</div>
<div
  @click="toggleCollapse(isSection2Collapsed)"
  :class={'isCollapsed': isSection2Collapsed}>
  Section 2
</div>
```

The error is

> Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ref'.ts(2345)

this is the obfuscated version of the code.. In the original version there are more sections, so normally I would like to avoid creating a method to collapse each section like so:

```
const toggleCollapseSection1 = () => {
  isSection1Collapsed.value = !isSection1Collapsed.value
}
const toggleCollapseSection2 = () => {
  isSection2Collapsed.value = !isSection2Collapsed.value
}
// repeat 18 more times
```

I also think that using the "keys" to determine the target reference is not the cleanest solution either (either the `switch` statement or `if`s).

```
const toggleCollapse = (sectionName: string) => {
if (sectionName == '1')
  isSection1Collapsed.value = !isSection1Collapsed.value
else
  isSection2Collapsed.value = !isSection2Collapsed.value
}
// repeat 18 more times
```

So I would like to know if it's possible to pass the references into functions from within the html code section as I've tried to do in the example above `@click="toggleCollapse(isSection2Collapsed)"`

Comment: "if it's possible to pass the references into functions" - afaik no, due to how refs work in templates. Could be XY problem, consider adding your case to the question, there may be more generalized solution to keep it DRY. The most obvious and straightforward is to use single object instead of multiple flag refs